# How does the computer differentiate between the letter and the correct one?

Tags: c++, symbols

in c++, When I declare a variable of the type of integer and give it a numerical value, for example, and when printing the variable, its numerical value appears, but when declaring a variable of the character type with the same value of the integer, the return value is a symbol, how is that.

Comment: Post some code that demonstrates what you're talking about.  There are lots of ways to interpret this question, we need something more specific.

Comment: Because an  "integer type" and a "character type" are different in a way that is visible to the compiler.  If the compiler is able to tell the difference, it is able to emit different code (or call different functions) to act on the different variables.

Comment: Careful with the terminology. You wrote "return value" but described the effects of writing a variable to an output stream.

Comment: See [operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) See **(1)** under the heading **basic_ostream and character**

Comment: Data type of C++ can help to understand.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ a `char` is an integer. It is a number, just like `short`, `int`, `long`, etc. One difference is that you don't know if `char` is signed with a range from -128 to 127, or unsigned with a range from 0 to 255.

However, even though a `char` is a number, it is usually used to represent an ASCII character value. So, that is what it defaults to. When you write `std::cout << 'c' << std::endl;` that `'c'` is written as a 'c' because that is probably what the programmer wanted to do. To get it to output as a number, you could do `std::cout << static_cast<int>('c') << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is numbers. Chars are numbers mapped to **ASCII** (1 byte per character) or **UNICODE**, which allows to represent almost any character of any language, but using more bytes.

Integers (and floats, longs, etc) are those numbers used for mathematical operations or a representation of themselves.

When you print something to screen the functions *printf* or *cout* take numbers (ints or chars) and display them as characters (letters or numbers) through pixel accommodation or a similar mechanism, whose specific dynamic it's not relevant at this point.

Declaring `char = 65;` it's the same as saying `char = 'A';` because at the end of the day the information on a char is stored and processed as a number.